# @Html.ActionLink in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

My action link in .cshtml is like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Reply", "Post_Reply", new { item.ID, item.Post_ID, item.Reply_ID })
```

and my method in controller is like this:

```
[Authorize]    
public ActionResult Post_Reply(int PostId=0, int Id = 0, int ReplyId = 0)   
{   
    post posts = new post();    
    posts.ID = Id;    
    return View(posts);   
}
```

but only value of item.ID is getting passed,
other two values item.Post_ID and item.Reply_ID are not getting passed..
Can anyone please guide me..
thanks..

Comment: What does the URL that gets generated look like?

Answer (score 7):

Looks like you are using the wrong overload for `@Html.ActionLink`:

Try:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Reply", "Post_Reply", new { Id = item.ID, PostId = item.Post_ID, ReplyId = item.Reply_ID }, null)
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that when you add in parameter values to an action link you must ALSO add Html Attributes, use this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Reply", "Post_Reply", new { Id = item.ID, PostId = item.Post_ID, ReplyId = item.Reply_ID }, null)
```

Adding the `Null` value for Html Attributes will allow the correct parameters to be sent

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
@Html.ActionLink("Reply", "Post_Reply", new { Id = item.ID, PostId = item.Post_ID, ReplyId = item.Reply_ID })
```

Your problem was that the anonymous object you passed didn't contain variable names, so it wouldn't be mapped onto your Action parameters.